# SQL Puzzle: Only monthly prices from a daily-prices table

Tags: sql, matlab

is it possible, to get just the first value of a month?

```
     Isin            Date          Price 
'AT0000652011'  '01-Jan-2004'   22,7700000000000
'AT0000652011'  '02-Jan-2004'   23,0300000000000
'AT0000652011'  '05-Jan-2004'   23,7000000000000
'AT0000652011'  '06-Jan-2004'   23,7000000000000
...
'AT0000652011'  '29-Jan-2004'   24,3800000000000
'AT0000652011'  '30-Jan-2004'   24,1900000000000
'AT0000652011'  '02-Feb-2004'   24,4500000000000
'AT0000652011'  '03-Feb-2004'   24,2900000000000
```

Here you see that sometimes the first of a month is on a weekend and thus there aren´t any prices?

This table is created in Matlab by

`Select List.* From List where List.Date between #01/01/2004# and #01/01/2005#`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
Select l.*
From l 
where l.date = (select min(l2.date)
                from list l2
                where l2.isin = l.isin and
                      year(l2.date) = year(l.date) and
                      month(l2.date) = month(l.date)
               );
```

Comment: 1. "... from list l2 where l2.isin..." I need to delete "list", right? Or is this a function? If it´s a function it doesn´t work :-D --- 2. Matlab is running for 15 minutes now although i reduced the query by " ... where l2.isin = l.isin and
                      year(l2.date) = year(l.date) and
                      month(l2.date) = month(l.date) and l2.date<#1/1/2007#" what is wrong?